# Delegating actions to KendoWidget Events

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, event-delegation

Consider this:
I got a standard shop app.

Goal: I want to display an info message in a `kendo window` before adding an article to the basket. Adding is only  performed by clicking "ok" or closing the window.

Currently:
There are specific functions for the different article types like:

```
    function addArticleType1ToBasket(){
//adds to basket
     doSomething1();
    }
    function addArticleType2ToBasket(){
//adds to basket
     doSomething2();
    }
```

What I am thinking of:

```
    function addArticleType1ToBasket(){
      //showsInfoMessage
      showInfoMessage();

     //adds to basket
     doSomething1();

    }

    function addArticleType2ToBasket(){
     //showsInfoMessage
     showInfoMessage();

     //adds to basket
     doSomething2();

    }

@(Html.Kendo().Window()
      .Name("infoMessage")
      .Visible(false)
      .Width(1000)
      .Draggable()
      .Title("Informations")
      .Actions(actions => actions.Close())
      //Here I want to call my delegate
      .Events(ev=>ev.Close("CallSpecificAction"))
      .Modal(true))
```

Now what I want to do is delegating the specific methods `doSomethingX()` to the event that fires when clicking "ok" or closing the window.

How would I do that?

thx

Comment: Why you don't use [Kendo Dialog](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/dialog/events) for this porpouse?

Comment: Good point. I might end up with use cases where Kendo.Dialog() is not providing full functionality..

Comment: Note that the widget was released on [Kendo UI R3 2016](http://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui/release-history/kendo-ui-r3-2016) so you need the framework at least updated to that version.